# Passing raw HTML to haml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Is it possible to pass pre formatted HTML to the haml file. For example I pass a variable such as:

```
my_text = "<b>this is bold</b>"
```

Then in my haml file:

```
%p
  =@my_text
```

I was hoping it would display **This is bold**
But it just returns the original string and ignores the tags surrounding "this is bold"

The goal is to highlight certain key words("one" and "two" in this example), here's a better example:

`@my_text = "This <b>one</b> plus <b>one</b> is a total of <b>two</b>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want to achieve, but i'd recommend that you keep your markup in the haml and plug in your copy in the instance variable like this.

## MyTextController.rb

```
@my_text = this is bold
```

## my_text.html.haml

```
%b
 = @my_text
```

**Edit after further clarification.**

You can use sanitize helper for this.

## my_text.html.haml

```
%p
= sanitize(@my_text, tags: %w(b))
```

Comment: The goal is to highlight certain key words("one" and "two" in this example), here's a better example:

`@my_text = "This <b>one</b> plus <b>one</b> is a total of <b>two</b>"`

Comment: Ah, I see. Lemme improve my answer then.

Comment: Awesome, that works perfect, and better than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh I figured it out, looks like you can do:

```
%p
  = raw @my_text
```